# How to edit a .txt file using python where I want to paste a specific string after every number

Tags: python, txt

9418012345, hello world. 
9418154321, hello world. 
94xxxxxxxx, hello world. 
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
1000 mobile number 
 but same message.
I already have mobile numbers pasted in every line. How can I add comma and same message after all numbers.

Comment: Read the file that has only the numbers, line by line. Write out new lines one by one, with the string, to a different file. Replace the first file with the second.

Answer (score 0):

You can read the file lines and store them in a list of strings and then add the string to all lines:

```
text_to_add = ', hello world'    

with open('numbers.txt') as f:
    lines = f.read().splitlines()
with open('result_file.txt', "w") as f:
    for line in lines:
        print(line + text_to_add, file=f)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
text_to_add = '' #add your text here

#create an file to write the new edited text

op_file = open("myfile.txt","a")#append mode

with open("myfile.txt") as fp:
    Lines = fp.readlines()
    for line in Lines:
        newline = str(line) + ',' + text_to_add
        op_file.write(newline+'\n')

op_file.close() #close the file
```

Comment: Thanks it worked with little tweaking wrt next line and spaces

Comment: then upvote the answer as accepted!!!

Answer (score 0):

Read the content and iterate over the lines by adding the message you want and then write it to a file again with new content.

```
message = "HelloWorld"
with open("number.txt") as fd:
    lines = fd.read().splitlines()
    
with open("file_with_text.txt","w") as fd:
    for line in lines:
        print(f'{line}, {message}', file=fd)
```